# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1" because "Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and want to make the default flutter app appear on my Android emulator. The emulator starts up fine but the process fails at "Gradle task assembly debug". I reinstalled everything ranging from Android Studio to flutter and dart and deleted the AVD from Android Studio then created it again but nothing seems to work. I tried a few potential fixes from youtube and google searches involving running a "gradle wrapper" command at the root directory but that doesn't work too as the root directories of all flutter apps lacks the "build.gradle" file. Flutter doctor does not show any problems.

Comment: is there any issue on `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: No there are no issues with it